# AngularJS hide preloader after repeater has finished

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a div that shows a preloader. I want to hide that div only after all of my data has finished loading in my ng-repeat.

**Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/ilgOZzIy2axSi5Iy85C7?p=preview

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="locationAccordionCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="location in locations" on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished">

      {{location.siteName}}

      <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="listOfLocations in location.locationsList track by $index">
              {{listOfLocations}}
          </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
App.controller('locationAccordionCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.locations = [
    {
      "siteName":"First Location",
      "locationsList":['First Location 1', 'First Location 2', 'First Location 3']
    },
    {
      "siteName":"Second Location",
      "locationsList":['Second Location 1', 'Second Location 2', 'Second Location 3']
    },
    {
      "siteName":"Third Location",
      "locationsList":['Third Location 1', 'Third Location 2', 'Third Location 3']
    }
  ];

// Hide preloader after repeater is finished loading data
App.directive('onFinishRender', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');
                });
            }
        }
    }
});

// hide preloader
$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
    $scope.hidePreLoader = true;
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `$broadcast` instead of `$emit`? Emit sents your event upwards in the scope hierarchy, while broadcast sends it downwards.

A sure way to fix the issue is to make the $rootScope broadcast the event downwards:

```
$rootScope.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');

$rootScope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
    $scope.hidePreLoader = true;
});
```

Comment: Can you get this to work in the plunker? http://plnkr.co/edit/ilgOZzIy2axSi5Iy85C7?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to add a method call to the ng-repeat block, e.g.

```
<div ng-repeat="location in locations" ng-init="clearLoader(($index + 1) == locations.length)">
    ...
</div>
```

And then in your controller

```
$scope.clearLoader = function (isLastItem) {
    if (isLastItem)
        $scope.hidePreLoader = true;
}
```